# Decentralized Storage for sensitive data

Tags: blockchain, storage

As the title says, is there any decentralized storage technology for storing sensitive data like the personal information of users? Concretely, I am developing a Dapp on blockchain, where users have to give their personal information for specific purposes. Now what I am missing is a technology to store such sensitive data in a way that users can trust me I'm not using their information for other purposes. This will work if data is stored on a decentralized storage that can interact with smartcontract, in addition, whenever users make a request, my smartcontract should be able to retrieve data from the storage (as an API). This [article](https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/tip/Comparing-4-decentralized-data-storage-offerings#:%7E:text=With%20decentralized%20storage%2C%20data%20is,providers%20cannot%20access%20the%20data.) shows 7 decentralized data storage networks that seem to work on my Dapp. But I'm a programmer and relatively new to blockchain so I don't really know which one is the best suit for my purposes and can be easily scaled up when more and more users enter. I'd like to hear your opinions, especially from those who worked/ is working on a similar projects to mine. Also, it would be great if someone can give me any application has been released that using such technology to store sensitive data. So far, I don't see any such application.

Any helps would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You may not want to store user data on the blockchain. [Smart contracts are not databases](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contracts-are-not-databases-5bb5926223be).

Answer (score 0):

[Pinata Cloud](https://www.pinata.cloud)

This site gives you the option to privatize your data through their Pro Plan(Submaring). $20 a month for this sadly, but it is the best product built on IPFS. It is primarily used for NFT’s, but you can use it for anything use Web3 related.

Comment: They have an API and your smart contract will be able to interact with your hidden data.